Is obex a unit of systemd?
I am following https://askubuntu.com/a/842391/ to enable obex service. Is obex a unit of systemd? Why I can't find it by
$ systemctl list-units | grep obex

?
It doesn't seem to exist, by
$ systemctl status obex 
Unit obex.service could not be found.

but why can it be enabled:
$ sudo systemctl --global enable obex

$ sudo systemctl  enable obex
Failed to enable unit: Unit file obex.service does not exist.

$ sudo systemctl --user enable obex
Failed to connect to bus: No medium found

$ systemctl --user enable obex
Created symlink /home/t/.config/systemd/user/dbus-org.bluez.obex.service → /nix/store/6dhjbf41xw7xyrmzp70vp7rhrcb047ir-bluez-5.64/etc/systemd/user/obex.service.
Created symlink /home/t/.config/systemd/user/obex.service → /nix/store/6dhjbf41xw7xyrmzp70vp7rhrcb047ir-bluez-5.64/etc/systemd/user/obex.service.


It's not a system service, but a per-user service (= part of the user's login session, has the same file access rights as the user), so try systemctl --user list-units and systemctl --user status obex. To start it immediately without a logout/login cycle, use systemctl --user start obex.
Since root is not currently logged-in, there is no user session D-Bus for root, but there is one for your current user account - that's why systemctl --user enable obex fails with sudo, but works without it.
